Bigquery: Load Dynamically Named CSV File from GCS
In Bigquery, I'm trying to schedule a daily query (which has LOAD DATA statement in it) job to load daily .csv file from GCS bucket. File name starts with a random hash and ends with current date, such as 7c4615_2024-08-28.csv.
This query won't work --
DECLARE URI array<string> default ['gs://my_bucket/*_' || format_date('%Y-%m-%d', current_date) || '.csv'];

load data overwrite `<PROJECT>.<DATASET>.<TABLE_NAME>`(name string)
  FROM FILES (
    format = 'CSV',
    uris = URI);

Error message:

Query error: Unable to determine if URI is a string or expression. If a string is intended, please enclose it with quotation marks. If an expression is intended, please enclose it with parentheses.

Looks like LOAD DATA statement doesn't like dynamically formatted URIs. Any way to achieve this using Bigquery SQL?
